# Getting NPE in location object in google maps

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am trying to get the current location in google maps.But i am getting the location object as NPE.The code is:

```
public void getcurrentlocation()
    {
         locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        // Getting Current Location
         location = getLocation();
     // Getting latitude of the current location
        current_latitude=location.getLatitude();
```

LOGCAT:

```
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.igloo.storelocater/com.igloo.storelocater.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at com.igloo.storelocater.MainActivity.getcurrentlocation(MainActivity.java:121)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at com.igloo.storelocater.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:99)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-16 10:42:13.335: E/AndroidRuntime(6340):     ... 11 more
```

Getting longitude of the current location:

```
     current_longitude= location.getLongitude();


}
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        100L,
                        1.0f, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        current_latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        current_longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            100L,
                            1.0f, this);
                    Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            current_latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            current_longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

The second method i got it from stackoverflow itself.But still i am getting the location object as null.Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Use if (isGPSEnabled && isNetworkEnabled)  instead if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)

and paste you else part inside it.

Comment: Why shoud i put the else part inside?It checks the case when only the network is present or only when gps is present.

Comment: Please undersatand the case assume if gps is available as well as internet  then isGPSEnabled =true && isNetworkEnabled = true, and the condition you wrote is  (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) so it goes to else but instead you could do  (isGPSEnabled && isNetworkEnabled) and put you else code inside. this makes code simple

Comment: Why is there a need to check it individually again separately inside for gps as well as network?